# Create VHD from C drive (Windows 7) to boot from using Hyper-V

Tags: vhd, hyper-v

Is it possible to create a VHD from the C drive running Windows 7 and then boot from the VHD using Hyper-V?

I have tried this using Dish2vhd by Sysinternals, but when I try to boot from the VHD in Hyper-V I get an error saying that the Bootmgr is missing.

Comment: You will need to check and load/unload the correct disk drivers if coming from a RAID or SCSI setup.

Comment: @phil - Have you tried to repair it?  Of course it also sounds like your not creating a VHD of the entire hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, I have not tried to repair it. I selected the C drive in Disk2vhd.

Comment: @HaydnWVN It comes from a SSD disk, how would I go through that process?